# Why WWE hosting their PPV Crown Jewel (2019) on Thursday instead of Sunday?

Tags: wwe

WWE used to host their PPV (Pay per view) on **Sundays**. Then, why WWE hosting their PPV [Crown Jewel (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_Jewel_(2019)) on **Thursday** instead of Sunday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events in Saudi Arabia do not follow the *normal* scheduling for WWE Pay-Per-Views.

- Greatest Royal Rumble - **Friday**, April 27, 2018
- Crown Jewel (2018) - **Friday**, November 2, 2018
- Super ShowDown - **Thursday** - June 7, 2019

For reasoning, one must assume that this is at the request and arrangement of the Saudi authorities and the WWE's internal scheduling requirements given the need for many of the Superstars to appear at live house shows and the Raw and Smackdown TV shows on Monday and Friday.